# $p(x)=x^4-2x^2-4$ is irreductible over $\mathbb Q.$

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification

I need to show that $p(x)=x^4-2x^2-4$ is irreductible over $\mathbb Q.$ Here's what I've done:

*Please tell me if it's correct*

Over $\mathbb C,$ $x^4-2x^2-4\\=(x^2-1)^2-5\\=(x^2-1+\sqrt 5)(x^2-1-\sqrt 5)\\=(x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt 5})(x-\sqrt{1+\sqrt 5})(x+\sqrt{1-\sqrt 5})(x-\sqrt{1-\sqrt 5})...(1)$

Since $\mathbb C[x]$ is an UFD so representing $p(x)$ as $(1)$ is unique upto rearrangement of the irreducible factors and inserting associates. So if we want to express $p(x)$ as $f(x)g(x)$ then $f,g$ must be some or all products of $(x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt 5}),$$(x-\sqrt{1+\sqrt 5}),$$(x+\sqrt{1-\sqrt 5}),$$(x-\sqrt{1-\sqrt 5})$ multiplied by a rational. As long as not all of them are taken the product won't belong to $\mathbb Q[x].$ So $p(x)$ can only be factored in the trivial way over $\mathbb Q.$

Comment: What's your argument that no other product will belong in $\mathbb Q[x]$?

Comment: This factorisation in $\mathbb R[X]$ is unique a[nd none of these four terms is in $\mathbb Q[X]$ so all we have to do is to check that none of the products of two of these four terms give a quadratic polynomial in $\mathbb Q[X]$ which is the case, hence the polynomial is not irreducible in  $\mathbb Q[X]$.

Comment: @palio Are you sure you don't also have to check all products of *three* factors?

Comment: yes you don't have to because even if the product of three of these terms give a degree three polynomial in $\mathbb Q[X]$, then still the fourth remaining term is not in   $\mathbb Q[X]$.

Comment: @palio Of course, sorry. The proof seems fine to me, then, once you add in that argument, and your calculations showing that no two-products are in $\mathbb Q[X]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all the participants of the discussion.